# Matlab: "Too many output arguments" when the correct number IS specified (AFAIK)

Tags: matlab, function, arguments, output, parameter-passing

I have this code: http://pastebin.com/E70c4UYY

When running, I get the following error:

```
Error using Diffusivity.getParams
Too many output arguments.

Error in Diffusivity.D_BA (line 63)
  [sigmaA, epsK_A] = Diffusivity.getParams(specieA);

Error in Diffusivity.D_Amix (line 95)
  Dam = fractionsArray(j) / Diffusivity.D_BA(specieA, fractionsArrayNames_cellstr{j}, T, P);
```

I do not understand how it can give an error, since in the code, on line 63 and 64 I have specified that there are two outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by changing line 9 from `[results] = getParams(specie)` to `[sigma, epsK] = getParams(specie)` and then just deleting line 54.